# Dispatch an action imported from another component and update the state accordingly in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Currently, I am working on a small project that has two pages. The first one has a list of items and the second has a form that adds new items to the list. For some reason, I set up redux store and actions to each page separately and that causes an issue. Now, when the adding of a new item succeeds, it navigates back to the page that renders the list. Yet, I can not refresh the list of items using an action from this page and I already submit the data from another page (which is the form). I believe there is a way to handle this using redux but I couldn't -so far- figure it out. Any help?

Regards

Comment: Can you add a reproducible code using codesandbox or any online IDE ? If not then add the code snippets where you think problem is occuring. It's hard to debug code without seeing it.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Thanks for your prompt response. There is no error actually. The point is, I want to use an action from a different component to update the state of the same component. For instance, I have "itemData" as a state in redux and the action that fetched the data is named, "fetchItems" and I want to use "fetchItems" in a different module to update the "itemData"